# xfce4 netload plugin, monitor on all interfaces?

Tags: networking, xfce

Is it possible to monitor all interfaces with xfce4's netload plugin?

Currently I can only place one interface name on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add a second, third monitor plugin, etc. afaik.

Maybe there is a trick to bundle the information yourself.

Comment: How do you monitor a second and third then?

Comment: You add the plugin another time to the panel, and name them, for example, wlan0, ppp0 and eth0.

Comment: thats annoying - I thought you meant could specify multiple interfaces in the plugin's settings (entering more than one, separated with varying characters does not work)... oh well I'll add to the bug report mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

There's an open feature request for this here https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3880. Both the issue and this question are quite old, but I think for other users can be good to know the answer at the time of writing is no (at least, using standard ways... probably you can somehow create a dummy interface mixing data from all interfaces, but I think it's easier to patch netload plugin :D ).